# How to add an inherited type using wcf data service client

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have an inheritance hierarchy where Owners, Tenants, Vendors and Agents are derived from People.  In my WCF Data Service client, I want to use AddObject to create a new Owner, but I cannot find how to do this.  When I try:

```
        var owner = new Owner()
        {
            FirstName = "Test"
            ,LastName = "Person"
            ,CheckName = "Test Person"
            ,PersonNo = "Test"
            ,UseFullNameForName = false
            ,TypeOfPerson = "Owner"
        };

        //Add
        context.AddObject("People", owner);
        context.SaveChanges();
```

the service throws a dynamic sql error.  I am using WCF Services 5.4 with EF 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

you should create the entity type of the table.

```
var person = new Person {
             FirstName = "Test"
            ,LastName = "Person"
            ,CheckName = "Test Person"
            ,PersonNo = "Test"
            ,UseFullNameForName = false
            ,TypeOfPerson = "Owner"
        };

context.Persons.AddObject(person);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The derived types have additional information that is stored in tables other than the People table.  If I do as you suggest, the related record in the other table will not be created.  I would expect that WCF Data Services would have a way of adding a derived object without having to explicitly handle the relationship.